# How to compare mysql varchar to string in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
public function getAttendance($date, $name) {

    $query = "SELECT CONVERT(db_obecnosci.attend USING utf8) FROM db_obecnosci WHERE attend_time = '".$date."' AND name = '".$name."'";
    $result= $this->db->select($query);

    if ($result == 'empty') {
        return 'P';
    }
    elseif ($result == 'present') {
        return 'O';
    }
    elseif ($result == 'apsent') {
        return 'N';
    }
    elseif ($result == 'late') {
        return 'S';
    }
    else {
        return 'P';
    }

}
```

I want co compare data from sql column:  attend to strings: empty, present, apsent and late. What I do wrong? Please help me.

```
public function select($query) { 
    $result = $this->link->query($query) 
                or die($this->link->error.__LINE__); 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
        return $result; 
    } else { 
        return false; 
    }
```

Link is sql object

I change to this:

```
public function getAttendance($date, $name) {

$query = "SELECT db_obecnosci.attend FROM db_obecnosci WHERE attend_time = '".$date."' AND name = '".$name."'";
$result= $this->db->select($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row["attend"] == 'empty') {
    return 'P';
}
elseif ($row["attend"] == 'present') {
    return 'O';
}
elseif ($row["attend"] == 'apsent') {
    return 'N';
}
elseif ($row["attend"] == 'late') {
    return 'S';
}
else {
    return 'P';
}

}
```

It works, but I have this error: 
[image: Error]

Comment: Now always run else

Comment: As this `$this->db->select($query);` is not vanilla PHP or MySQL access API code, What does that method do?

Comment: What does `$result` look like, is it a string, a resource an array, etc.?

Comment: Method select do this:

public function select($query) {

$result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 return $result;
}
else {
 return false;
}

Comment: Please add that to the question. Is `link` a mysqli object? If so `query()` returns a result object, you need to fetch it.  I also would give an alias to `CONVERT(db_obecnosci.attend USING utf8)` so it is easily accessible in the array.

Comment: I do not know what the result looks like, because I can not throw it $ result ito screen.

Comment: That method never actually **FETCHES** anything from the resultset. So you are returning a HANDLE to a resultset and NOT the actual results

Comment: Do `print_r($result);` or `var_dump($result);` in your function, I think you have a result object. If that is the case see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php.

Comment: print_r give me this:
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )